# Impossible to get my $params in Laravel scope

Tags: laravel, scope

I'm new in Laravel and I try to do a list a table. On this list I have some filters.
I try to use scope but It doesn't work.

**In my controller I have** :

```
class GrillesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(request $request)
    {


     $query = DB::table('grilles')
        ->join('compets as CO','CO.id','=','gri_compet_id')
        ->join ('journees as JO', 'JO.id','=','gri_journee_id')
        ->select('com_nm_logo','jou_l_journee_c','grilles.*')
        ->where('com_c_st','A')
        ->orderbyRaw('gri_d_deb,gri_h_deb,com_n_ord_aff');

    $params = $request->except('_token');
    $grilles = Grilles::FilterListe($query,$params)->get();
```

**In my model :**

```
public function scopeFilterListe($query,$params)
{
    $value = $params['filter_compets'];


    $query->where('gri_compet_id','=',$value);
    return $query;
}
```

In `scopeFilterListe` in the model, I'd like to get all my variable of my URL to build my where clause.

http://xxx.fr/grilles?_token=DMcay7SkDc1QeFlxRPMqT4DTGJXdgcXRbVbCNRvo&filter_compets=1&filter_etatparis=3&filter_periode=

I tried a lot of things, but I always have this error:

> "Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as
>   array"

It comes from : `$value = $params['filter_compets'];`
If I write `$value=1`, it works...(even if I have another problem as the data supposed to come from

```
->join('compets as CO','CO.id','=','gri_compet_id')
->join ('journees as JO', 'JO.id','=','gri_journee_id')
```

are not displayed..

What is the problem for my scope ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need dynamic scope. Please find documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

Herewith your modified script.

```
public function scopeOfFilterListe($query,$value)
{
    $query->where('gri_compet_id','=',$value);
    return $query;
}
```

```
$query = DB::table('grilles')
        ->join('compets as CO','CO.id','=','gri_compet_id')
        ->join ('journees as JO', 'JO.id','=','gri_journee_id')
        ->select('com_nm_logo','jou_l_journee_c','grilles.*')
        ->where('com_c_st','A')
        ->orderbyRaw('gri_d_deb,gri_h_deb,com_n_ord_aff')
   ;

$params = $request->except('_token');
$grilles = Grilles::ofFilterListe($params['filter_compets'])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i did a litlle bit differently but in fact I didn't get that I haven't to initialize $query before the call to the scope.